# what does parallelstream().map().map() do?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Collection` with encoded objects (which are quite big when not encoded) and I was wondering what actually happens if I would do something like:

```
codes.parallelStream().map(code -> decode(code)).map(obj -> do1(obj) * do2(obj));
```

As I didn't find much more info about this kind of constructions, I suppose this first decodes all elements and only afterwards performs the real task, but on the other hand it would be more logical (and memory-friendly in case of big objects) in case of a `parallelStream` if it would execute both maps at once for every element, like if there was standing:

```
codes.parallelStream().map(code -> { obj = decode(code); return do1(obj) * do2(obj); });
```

Could anybody help me understand how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` operation is evaluated lazily. Therefore the `decode` operation in the first `map` call will only be performed if the encoded object is evaluated by the terminal operation of the Stream. Therefore your `I suppose this first decodes all elements and only afterwards performs the real task` assumption is false, since the terminal operation may require just few of the elements of the source Collection to be processed, so neither of the 2 `map` operations will be performed for most of the encoded elements in this case.

An intermediate Stream operation may be processed for all the elements of the Stream only if it requires all the elements (for example `sorted()` must iterate over all the elements), or if it precedes an intermediate operation that requires all the elements (for example in `...map().sorted()...`, executing `sorted()` requires first executing `map()` on all the elements of the Stream).

Your two code snippets should behave similarly, though the first one is more readable.

Comment: Thanks already, but if I collect the results of my 2 maps to store them in a new `Collection` for instance, they would be evaluated, right?

Comment: @MrTsjolder Yes, but each source object would be evaluated across all the Stream pipeline's methods before the the object is evaluated in the same thread. So if your parallel stream uses 2 threads to execute the pipeline, each thread would finish processing one encoded object (i.e. running both `map()` calls) before proceeding to the next.